# getting unexpected invalid filter.created_at[from] error message

Tags: soundcloud

I'm making this kind of SoundCloud API request:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=electro&limit=10&client_id=<my-client-id-that-I-removed-intentionally>&created_at%5Bfrom%5D=2014%2F11%2F24%2012%3A03%3A04&offset=0
```

and since recently, I'm getting this response:

code: 400,

body:

```
{"errors":[{"error_message":"invalid filter.created_at[from] value: '2014/11/24 12:03:04'"}]}
```

My request should be fine, according to the official documentation:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

Could you please tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks for the support in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the date format. The [docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) say dashes should be used in dates:

```
created_at[from]    date    (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) return tracks created at this date or later
```

So it will work when you specify the date like this: `2014-11-24 12:03:04` (not with slashes).

We at SoundCloud recently changed the behaviour of the API to return errors for all kinds of for invalid input in filters in order to be clearer about what is allowed and what can be expected.

Comment: Was I blind?! Thank you, maxjakob!